# passing class objects in C++

Tags: c++, object, c++11, reference, parameter-passing

I'm taking a C++ course and I'm stuck on classes and objects. I'm working on an assignment that, in a nutshell, creates a class that takes two variables (let's say length and width).

I've figured out how to do this using get and set functions. But then, we have to use math on these variables. We're supposed to write a function that takes one instance of the class as a parameter (so two variables), and then does math on both this object (the one taken as a parameter) and object that the method of was called.

Part of why I'm confused is the language, and I'm not sure exactly what that means. So far, like I said, I managed to be able to end up with setLength and setWidth variables set via user input.  I am really, really stuck on trying to then pass these values (or this object?) to a function and then call the method of another object?

Maybe if someone could help me figure out what "taking an object as a parameter and then doing math on the object i called the method of" means?  Or just help with passing objects?

Comment: For example think of a `string` (or `std::string`). I can say `string myString = "test";` and have a string set to "test". What does that mean? A string is an object, made (or instantiated) from a class. It contains a pointer to a character array inside (presumably) and defines functions for interacting with other strings. For example I can say `myString.compare(anotherString)` and it will take another object of the string class and compare itself to that string, and return an `int`.

Comment: _"I figure if I can engage in a dialogue and ask questions it will help me understand!"_ Then you are not looking for a Q&A repository, but a chatroom. Fortunately, we have some of those here...

Answer (score 5):

Passing an object works just like passing other kinds of variables. If you were passing an integer into a function, you'd use this syntax for declaring the function:

```
void myFunction(int myInt);
```

and if you were passing in an object of class `Foo`, it would be:

```
void myOtherFunction(Foo myFoo);
```

This is sort of like saying, "This the thing I want you to use in your calculations. Copy the object I pass in here!. Passing by reference instead:

```
void myFunction(int &myInt);
void myOtherFunction(Foo &myFoo);
```

lets you modify the value you pass. It's also significantly cheaper with larger objects than *passing by value* which was the original syntax in this answer. You can think of it as you saying to the computer, "I know you want this value, but I'm not going to let you copy this. Just look over *there*, instead, and you'll find what I want you to work with." But sometimes you don't want to modify the thing you're working with!

Sure, you could be *very careful* in your function to avoid changing things, but the C++ language lets you say that you shouldn't modify the variable, and then will check that you don't modify it for you!

This can be accomplished by using

```
void yetAnotherFunction(const Foo &myFoo);
```

The `const` is what says "Don't let me be modified!" to the compiler, and the compiler will listen.

---

Say you want to assign a few values to a simple object, using a (non-member) function:

```
// a struct should usually hold simple groups of data, 
// that don't do much by themselves. Their members are 
// also public by default.
struct MySimpleType{ 
    int first;
    int second;
};

// object is passed by reference so it can be modified.
void modifier(MySimpleType &object, int newFirst, int newSecond){
    object.first = newFirst;
    object.second = newSecond;
}
```

then in your client code (probably a `main` function, at this point in your coding career) you do this:

```
MySimpleType object;

modifier(object, 13, 12);

cout << object.first << ", " << object.second;
```

which should print out:

```
13, 12
```

Comment: If your object is large, and you do not want to change it, pass by `const` reference: `void myOtherFunction(const Foo &myFoo);`.

Comment: thanks.  so, if I just create a class object and try to pass it to a function, nothing happens because just by creating the object you aren't necessarily assigning any parameters, right?  So in my case, I'm taking user input.  I can't seem to figure out how to "assign" this user input to the object.   So in the example above, i have setLength variables taken from user input.  I cant figure out how to assign these variables to a new object, so that then the object is passes, the user input ( in the form of variables) is passed along with it!  thanks!

Comment: @user877329 edited to include `const` explanation. Thanks for pointing out I missed it.

Comment: @FKAjasmine Provide a member function `get(std::istream`& is) for your class, to allow reading member values from an input stream.

Comment: @FKAjasmine edited to include an example of setting members of a class in a function.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking of pieces of code as "objects" can be difficult a first, but it will likely be one of the most important things you learn (because object oriented programming is widely used in industry and academia). There is quite a lot of background you need in order to use objects effectively in c++, but I'll try give a concise introduction..

Firstly, it's important that you understand the difference between a "class" and an "object." A class is an abstraction that allows you to define an object. If I want to make a `Horse` object, I use a `Horse` class to define what is important about a horse. This class might have fields defining its name, owner, hair color etc. However, the `Horse` class is not a horse. It tells you what it means to be a `Horse`, but it isn't one. In order to define an "object" of type `Horse`, we would write the following:

```
Horse myHorse = new Horse("Sea Biscuit", "Howard", "Black");
```

Keep in mind that `Horse` is the class, but Sea Biscuit is the horse itself (the object).

You may be well aware of the above, but it can often be a tough concept to grasp, so I thought I would mention it.

Now, if you want to perform math on some objects, this is relatively straightforward with using member functions. Lets define a new class to do some math on (because horses and math don't mix).

```
class Wallet
{
    int _pennies;

    // This is a constructor. It allows us to write: Wallet myWallet(100);
    public Wallet(int pennies)
    {
        _pennies = pennies;
    }

    public void addPennies(int pennies)
    {
        _pennies = _pennies + pennies;
    }

    public void stealPennies(Wallet &stolenWallet)
    {
        int stolenPennies = stolenWallet._pennies;
        stolenWallet._pennies = 0;

        this.addPennies(stolenPennies);
    }
}
```

We can now make some objects, and modify the fields in both objects with a single call to `stealPennies`:

```
int main()
{
    Wallet myWallet(10); // Creates a wallet with 10 cents.
    Wallet anotherWallet(50); // Creates another wallet with 50 cents.

    myWallet.stealPennies(anotherWallet);
    // myWallet now has 60 cents, and anotherWallet has none.
}
```

**Note:** The `&` before the name of the argument in the `stealPennies` function means it will be passed by *reference*. Usually when you pass an argument to a function it is passed by *value*, which means the variable in the function is a copy of the argument you passed. Putting the `&` before the name of the argument means the variable in the function is the same variable instead of a copy. (This is highly simplified.. it's unlikely that you will be able to fully understand passing by reference until you become familiar with *pointers*). Also, it is common practice to use some kind of naming convention when defining variables that are part of a class. Putting an underscore before the variable name is common (such as `_pennies` in this example).

Hopefully this is helpful to you (and hopefully it works, as I can't test it at the moment). I have tried to make the code as readable and explicit as possible.

Comment: Reads very confused and unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

As from your comment:

> *" I can't seem to figure out how to "assign" this user input to the object. So in the example above, i have setLength variables taken from user input. I cant figure out how to assign these variables to a new object, so that then the object is passes, the user input ( in the form of variables) is passed along with it!"*

What I think you actually need is some function(s) to manipulate your class member variables by reading from a `std::istream`, and passing the object instance targeted as a reference:

```
class foo {
public:
    foo() : x(12), y(42.0) {}
private:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, foo& subject);
    std::istream& getfrominstream (std::istream& is) {
        is >> x;
        is >> y;
        return is;  
    }
    int x;
    double y;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, foo& subject) {
   return subject.getfrominstream(is);
}
```

---

Call like:

```
int main() {
    foo f;
    std::cin >> f;
}
```